# Sentence with Akkusativ Präposition or Dativ

Tags: sentence-structure, dative, accusative

> Ich habe eine Tasche **für meinen Bruder.**
>   Ich habe **meinem Bruder** eine Tasche.

The first sentence with Akkusativ preposition while the second one with Dativ. Which one is correct? Or may be both?

Comment: You are missing a verb, that's not a complete sentence. For instance _Ich habe meinem Bruder eine Tasche **geschenkt**._ would be and using Dativ.

Comment: @KhadimAli: it is perfectly OK to just edit a post without mentioning as long as we do not have an answer refering to this. Even then, if it was an obvious typo unrelated to the question we should edit it out to make our issue clear.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay, not complete but not wrong either? Or is it wrong to say incomplete sentence like this in Deutsch? If you post this as a answer too that would be great.

Comment: @KhadimAli Incomplete sentences make no sense usually.

Comment: The reason why native speakers are confused is the verb *haben* can mean *to possess*, but much more often it's an auxiliary for perfect tense. We miss the needed past participle *gekauft* in your second example. This is needed because *haben* in the meaning *to possess* has no receiver == dative object. But you have one in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You present an interesting pair of sample sentences. Indeed, from the viewpoint of pure grammar, both sentences are "correct", but the second

> *Ich habe meinem Bruder eine Tasche

is so unusual that almost everybody will tell you it is wrong.

I, however, claim that it is grammatically acceptable. Why? There are both in dialects of German and in German colloquial language various expressions that use exactly your syntactical construct, although with other topics:

> Hast du mir mal 'ne Zigarette?

*Do you have a cigarette for me?*

> Hier, ich hab' dir ein Geschenk.

*Here, I have a present for you.*

But, as I said, this is very specifically colloquial language. These things do not work that way in (orderly) written language. So, as learner of German: just do  not use it actively. But do not be puzzled when you hear it in some informal conversation.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you are confusing two concepts:

- doing or having something *for someone else* and
- expressing that *someone is the receipient of an action*.

Let us consider the following two sentences, which differ only in the verb:

> 1. Ich kaufe eine Tasche. → I buy a bag.
> 2. Ich habe eine Tasche. → I have a bag.

Now, we want to express that the bag is for your brother. In both cases, you can do this using the accusative preposition *für*:

> 1. Ich kaufe eine Tasche *für meinen Bruder*. → I buy a bag *for my brother*.
> 2. Ich habe eine Tasche  *für meinen Bruder*. → I have a bag *for my brother*.

For the verb *kaufen* there is another possibility: The act of buying can have a recepient, i.e., your brother; and this can be expressed in terms of a dative object. However, this does not work with *haben*; the act of having something does not have a receipient.

> 1. Ich kaufe *meinem Bruder* eine Tasche. → I buy *my brother* a bag.
> 2. <s>Ich habe *meinem Bruder* eine Tasche. → I have *my brother* a bag.</s>